# What is difference between use &a and a

Tags: c

What is the difference read a number to `&a` and just `a`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a;

    printf("A:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Address:%p\n",&a);
    printf("value A:%d",a);

    return (0);
}
```

Sometimes I see code where instead reading to variable they read to the address i know variables are just memory but is not the same? i can do both ? or sometimes i have to use one of these in particular ?

Comment: Passing `&a` means you are passing the address of `a` to `scanf()`. Just passing `a` means that `a` is a pointer to an `int`. Note that `scanf()` expects an address of some kind.

Comment: You should _always_ use a pointer to read data for a variable when using `scanf`. In C every argument is passed by value, if the behaviour of passing a value to `scanf()` using the `%d` option was defined it would create a copy of `a` and write to that, which is useless to you as you then have no way to access that data.

Comment: The documentation for both [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/scanf) and [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) specify the requirements for what each expects for corresponding arguments matched against the format specifiers.  Using the address-of operator `&` is required in the cases so-noted in that documentation.

Comment: *"instead reading to variable they read to the address*". But your code *does* read to the address of the variable. You cannot supply the (value of a) variable to read into.

Comment: What does your C textbook say about it?

Comment: So what is your problem, you aren't clear enough what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 3):

In C, if you want a function to modify the value of an object (such as `a` in the `scanf` call), you must pass a *pointer to* that object.  A pointer is any expression that evaluates to the *location* of an object in memory.  In this case, the pointer to `a` is obtained by using the unary `&` operator:

```
scanf( "%d", &a ); // write an integer value to a
```

You can create a pointer variable that serves much the same purpose:

```
int a;
int *p = &a;       // the object p stores the location of a
                   // p points to a

scanf( "%d", p );  // also writes an integer value to a through the pointer p
                   // note no & here because p is already a pointer type
```

If you just want to pass an object's value to a function, you wouldn't use the `&` operator:

```
printf( "%d", a ); // write the value stored in a to standard output, 
                   // formatted as a decimal integer
```

If you have a pointer, and you want the value of the thing the pointer points to, you'd use the unary `*` operator:

```
printf( "%d", *p ); // write the value stored in a to standard output,
                    // going through the pointer p
```

To summarize,

```
 p == &a  // int * == int *
*p ==  a  // int   == int
```

Comment: thank you for your help ! i think i get it , i was a little confuse